# How to enable the accelorometer in Dell Inspiron Duo

Tags: 11.10, hardware, resolution, dell, tablet

I am considering on getting a Dell Duo Tablet PC. I love the idea of a tablet, but there are some things that just need a physical keyboard (no the iPad is NOT immune to this!!) and I hate to have to buy 2 devices, money wise and for passing data back and forth.

The only thing that keeps me from committing to the Dell Duo as a solid Ubuntu tablet is that it would suck to have to use an Applet to change the orientation of the screen. Is there a way to recognize the orientation sensor and configure it?

I am FAR from a knowledgeable Linux user, but I can follow tutorials easily and I learn quickly, and as long as the commands are either simple, or can be copy and pasted, then I don't mind jumping into a terminal.

If I can have it confirmed that this is possible, than this machine will almost undoubtedly be my next portable computing device. Only downsides seem to be battery life and the processor can't handle 1080p videos. Both things I could deal with for a portable machine that can serve multiple purposes :)

p.s. Multi-touch has been fixed in  11.10 hasn't it?

Comment: For what I know, the Duo tablet has a Broadcom HD Crystal decoder, which lets it play up to 1080p videos instead of handling them to the low Atom processor. And I believe that the Crystal chipset is supported by Ubuntu. Battery life may be a permament downside, since Ubuntu is more power-consuming than Windows, and also the Duo has a 4-cell battery, which is minimal. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

This is the only patch I found to help you out.

Make sure you have the module i2c_i801 loaded to create the sysfs entry `/sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-2` (note: since I upgraded my install it now appears as `/sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-14` - you may need to work out which i2c bus has the i801 attached)

Building and loading this module, you can then instantiate the device with: `echo lsm303dlh_a 25 > /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-2/new_device and enable it with echo 1 > /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-2/2-0019/mode`.

[Read it all here](http://lukeross.name/dell/#accelerometer)

Comment: I have actually decided against the Duo, for many reasons including the horrible battery and not being able to easily replace the battery.

Comment: I have actually decided against the Duo, for many reasons including the horrible battery and not being able to easily replace the battery. But thank you for searching for that!! If someone with a Duo tests this and finds it works, please let me know so we can mark this as an answer!!